# Project Rendering in Black and White?

Tags: color

I am brand new to blender and have been working on some really basic things. When I look at it in solid mode everything is in color but when I look at it in the material preview mode, render preview mode, or when I render it out the whole thing is in Black and White. Under Output Properties, the color is set to RGBA. If anyone could help that would be great. Thanks!

Comment: This is one project I have been working on rendering in black & white. https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/JEw60eDl/

Answer (score 1):

Hi @TobiasPenner and welcome. When I opened your Blend file I noticed that the two plains have a white emission material and the cube has the default light-gray. So when you say you viewed as colour I am not sure what you mean. You may have changed a few things before submitting the file, but maybe if you showed an image of the different modes it will help.

Anyhow with your blend file if you want to add color to the cube and see in Material preview mode you will need to do the following:

1. Change your cube to view as a solid object (it is displayed as a wireframe). 
   [image]
2. Assign a color in the material properties of the object 
   [image]